# Did I pick the error? Mathematical Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Given these propositions:
$$\begin{align}
x&=y \\
x^2&=xy \\
x^2-y^2&=xy-y^2\\
x+y&=y\\
y+y&=y\\
2y&=y\\
2&=1
\end{align}
$$
I've found out that the error is "$x+y=y$". Am I correct? I'm just a beginner in Discrete Math.

Comment: You divided by $x-y$, which is $0$.

Comment: Thank you! I missed that part.

Comment: Right the beginning is wrong: $x=y\Leftrightarrow x^2=xy$ holds iff $x\neq0$.

Comment: Actually it still holds if $x=0$ @MichaelHoppe you get $0=0$ which is true. In fact say we have $2x=4$ and you multiply by $0$ to get $0=0$. What you did was ok, but as it is true $0=0$ .But it doesn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Um, sort of? It's supposed to be factoring both sides of the equation into

$$(x-y)(x+y)=(x-y)y$$

and dividing by $x-y$ to yield

$$x+y=y$$

which seems fine at first glance. But the problem is when you divide by $x-y$ you're actually dividing by $0$ because $x=y$.

Comment: Well, in the first step you might multiply by zero ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe first step in my answer or first step in the original post? If you mean the original post, you can choose any nonzero $x=y$ and the argument is "valid" until you get to where my answer starts, and you're at $0=0$ and then you end up dividing that by $0$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}x=y\\
x^2=xy\\
x^2-y^2=xy-y^2\\
(x-y)(x+y) = (x-y) y
\end{align}
and then you divide by zero to get the next line. That is the mistake.

Answer (score -1):

The fish rots from the head: $x=y\Leftrightarrow x^2=xy$ holds iff $x\neq0$.

Comment: Why will this not hold for $x=0$?

Comment: For example, $(0,42)$ is a solution of $x^2=xy$, but not of $x=y$. Hence the solution set of the statement form $x^2=xy$ is larger than the solution set of $x=y$.  From here you may deduce $x=y\Rightarrow x^2=xy$, but not vice versa.

Comment: Dearest downvoter, would you please so kind to explain your decision?

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted. Another way to phrase this for whoever downvoted: say you have $y=2$ and $x=0$. Then $x^2=xy$ but $x\ne y$, so @tatan there's an example of the $\iff$ not holding for $x=0$

Comment: I didn't down vote but in your example it is true that $x^2=xy$ if $x=y$ as we have $0=0$. But you cannot reverse this statement and say that if $x^2=xy$ then $x=y$ because $x=0$ and then you'll be dividing by $0$. @AlexMathers

Comment: What he/she says is right. But it does not answer the question. Notice he/she had a two way implication, not just a one way. @tatan .

Comment: @MichaelHoppe the fact that $x = 0$ implies $x=y \Leftrightarrow x^2 = xy$ means your statement is incorrect (as it tells us that $x = y \Leftrightarrow x^2 = xy$ doesn't imply $x \neq 0$). Also, in the original question there's no indication that there should be backwards as well as forwards implications between the statements.

Comment: A bit late perhaps, but I downvoted. The fact that $x^2=xy$ does not always imply $x=y$ is not what is wrong with this proof. How can it be? After all, it's never used. This makes your answer "not useful" (IMHO), which is why I downvoted.